# How do I obtain the transfer logs of an ERC721 token through Etherscan?

Tags: transactions, tokens, etherscan

Is it possible to get the transfer logs of a specific ERC721 token ID using Etherscan API? For example,  https://etherscan.io/token/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d?a=587058#readContract
I went through their documentation but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it at the following link.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d
https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#tokentxnsErc721

Comment: I need to obtain those info through API for further computation